# Perl script to compress strings replacing repeated chars

Tags: string, perl

I'm writing a perl script that, given a list of string as input, similar to this:

```
AADDDDKPP PrRRRR
wwwwwwwwwwYY SSSSS SSSSGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
ZZZZZFZZQZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

should substituite every char that is repeated more than 2 times consecutively with the number of repetitions followed by the char. So with the input showed above, the script should give in output these strings:

```
AA4DKPP Pr4R
10wYY 5S 4S14G
5ZFZZQ13Z
```

Here's the perl script I've written so far:

```
foreach my $line(@lines){
    @letters=split("",$line);
    @alreadyChecked=();
    foreach my $letter(@letters){
        $count=0;
        if (grep {$letter} @alreadyChecked) {
            next;
        }
        push(@alreadyChecked,$letter);
        foreach my $index(@letters){
            if($letter eq $index){
                $count=$count+1;
            } else {
                @alreadyChecked=0;
                last;
            }  
        }
        if($count>2){
            @chops=split(/$letter+/,$line);
            $line=$chops[0].$count.$letter.$chops[1];
        }
    }
}
```

I think there's more than one flaw in this code, but can't find where.

Comment: How do you want digits in the input string handled? Your example does not include any so perhaps there are none. But it would be helpful to have clarification.

Comment: why do you want to compress the string this way in particular?

Comment: @ysth It's just an exercise I'm doing for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $str ="
AADDDDKPP PrRRRR
wwwwwwwwwwYY SSSSS SSSSGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
ZZZZZFZZQZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
";

$str =~ s/((.)\2{2,})/ length($1) . $2  /ge;

print $str;
```

output

```
AA4DKPP Pr4R
10wYY 5S 4S14G
5ZFZZQ13Z
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Way faster and more polished.

Comment: @TLP don't know what are you talking about, I saw your answer after I've posted `s/((.)\2{2,})/ length($1) . $2  /ge;`

Comment: I'm quite a noob with regex, so I get what the rest of your regex is doing but still, what is that \2 for? Thanks again.

Comment: @Andrew `\2` is everything captured by second group => `(.)` On the right side of substitution, that same group is referenced by `$2`

Comment: @mpapec Yeah, nevermind... it was just very annoying. When my answer was done, you started writing yours, even though it was identical to mine. But I guess it was within the "grace period" -- 1:09 is not much time. And even more annoying, the OP asked you for an explanation that was already in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with a regex substitution:

```
perl -plwe's/((.)\2\2+)/length($1) . $2/eg'
```

This will check for repetition of a character `\2`, captured by the inner parenthesis, and replace it with a number representing the length of the entire match `$1` followed by the character itself `$2`. The script version could be something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    s/((.)\2\2+)/length($1) . $2/eg;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The power of regex.